# Calling getBBox for a SVG text element in a Seed Rust application

Tags: svg, rust, rust-wasm, rust-seed

I just made my first steps with WASM and [Seed](https://seed-rs.org/) which was a very smooth experience so far. I was able to create SVG using `svg!`, `circle!`, `text!`, ... and similar macros. To generate my SVG in the proper way, I have to measure text. My idea is to generate SVG text nodes and call [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) on the node. I figured out that Seed is using [web_sys](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/index.html) and that [getBBox is implemented there](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.SvgTextContentElement.html#method.get_b_box).

My problem is how to get from the `Node` created by `text!` to the [SvgTextElement](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.SvgTextElement.html). I tried to access the `node_ws` field, but it seems to be "empty". It might not yet been created, but I don't now enough about the Seed internals.

So how do I create a SVG text node so that I can call getBBox on it before generating the "main" SVG nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`el_ref`](https://docs.rs/seed/0.8.0/seed/virtual_dom/el_ref/fn.el_ref.html) to get a  reference to the DOM element. Something like this ought to work:

```
struct Model {
    element: ElRef<web_sys::SvgTextElement>,
}

fn view(model: &Model) -> Node<Msg> {
    svg!![
        text![
            el_ref(&model.element),
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    ]
}

fn init(orders: &mut impl Orders<Msg>) -> Model {
    orders.after_next_render(|_| Msg::Rendered);
    // ...
}

fn update(msg: Msg, model: &mut Model, orders: &mut impl Orders<Msg>) {
    match msg {
        Msg::Rendered => {
            let element = model.element.get().expect("no svg text element");
            let b_box = element.get_b_box();
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```